# Can you stop a button click event executing from a method it called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, error-handling, webforms

So I have the regular button click event which already checks to see if data for the same club, pitch, time & date exist and if not inserts the new record.

I also now have some error handling to check if the timedate is in the right format or is longer than 2 hours.

Is it possible to stop the execution of the button click event based on the results of these error handles if they're placed in a separate method called from the button click event? or is it a case of nesting all the if together in the button click event?

Here is my btnBook code:

```html
 protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime();
        if (txtBookingName.Text != "" & txtUserID.Text != "" & txtUserName.Text != "" & ddlClub.SelectedValue != "Select Club" & ddlPitches.SelectedValue != "Select Pitch" & end.Value != "" & start.Value != "" & txtDescription.Text != "")
        {

            //Helped by forum post to check if timeslot is already booked (www.forums.asp.net/t/2050551.aspx?Validation+to+Check+Duplicate+Records+)
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                //Open your connection
                conn.Open();
                //Your Select Query
                //Change this as per your design and provide the primary key field here
                string selectString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Booking WHERE ClubID = @ClubID And PitchID = @PitchID And StartTime = @StartTime And EndTime = @EndTime";
                //Create Command object
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(selectString, conn);
                //Pass your parameter here
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubID", ddlClub.SelectedItem.Value);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PitchID", ddlPitches.SelectedItem.Value);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", Convert.ToDateTime(start.Value));
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndTime", Convert.ToDateTime(end.Value));
                // Get the Result query
                var idExists = (Int32)myCommand.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

                //Check if record exists in table
                if (!idExists)
                {
                    //Insert the Record
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Booking (BookingName, UserID, ClubID, PitchID, StartTime, EndTime, Description) values(@BookingName, @UserID, @ClubID, @PitchID, @StartTime, @EndTime, @Description)", conn);
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@BookingName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBookingName.Text;
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(txtUserID.Text);
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ClubID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(ddlClub.SelectedItem.Value);
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@PitchID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt16(ddlPitches.SelectedItem.Value);
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@StartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(start.Value);
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@EndTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(end.Value);
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDescription.Text;

                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                        MsgBox("Your booking has been placed", this.Page, this);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MsgBox("The time slot for your selected Club & Pitch has already been booked. Please choose another", this.Page, this);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MsgBox("Please fill in all the required information", this.Page, this);
        }


    }
```

And here is the method I hoped to use to group the error checking in:

```html
 public void DateTime()
    {
        //Helped by tutorial (www.asp-net-example.blogspot.ie/2009/01/aspnet-date-time-example-how-to-get_2137.html)
        DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(start.Value);
        DateTime endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(end.Value);
        TimeSpan difference = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
        double totalHours = difference.TotalHours;
        lblBookMessage.Text += "Total Hours Difference: " + totalHours;

        if (totalHours > 2)
        {
            MsgBox("You cannot book a slot for more than 2 hours at a time", this.Page, this);
        }

        //Forum post to verify datetime format is correct (www.forums.asp.net/t/2067633.aspx?validate+textbox+on+button+click)
        bool flagStart = true;
        string strStart = start.Value.Trim();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strStart))
        {
            //validate the format dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(strStart, "^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\\/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\\/(201)\\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-0][0-0]$"))
            {
                //Don't Meet the requirements
                flagStart = false;
                MsgBox("Please enter a valid date and an on the hour time", this.Page, this);
            }

        }
        lblBookMessage.Text = flagStart.ToString();

        bool flagEnd = true;
        string strEnd = end.Value.Trim();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strEnd))
        {
            //validate the format dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(strEnd, "^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\\/([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\\/(201)\\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-0][0-0]$"))
            {
                //Don't Meet the requirements
                flagEnd = false;
                MsgBox("Please enter a valid date and an on the hour time", this.Page, this);
            }

        }
        lblBookMessage.Text = flagEnd.ToString();


    }
```

Comment: Have you considered validation controls?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to refactor your code. It looks messy when you see so many lines of code in the button click handler. Divide your logic into two methods. If possible move them to business logic class. 
Based on information provided. You can do check for the validation of date and data into two methods both returning bool. and you can place check of inside the button click event like..

protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

string outmessage=string.empty;

```
       if(ValidateDate(starttime,endtime,out outmessage) && ValidateData(txtBookingName.Text,txtUserID.Text, txtUserName.Text, ddlClub.SelectedValue, ddlPitches.SelectedValue , end.Value , start.Value ,txtDescription.Text, out outmessage))
       {
            // all valid 
           lblMessage.Text=outmessage;
        }
      else
       {
             //something is wrong.
           MessageBox.Show(outmessage);
       }


 }
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly and hopefully my answer helps you too.